# Convert list to 2d matrix

Tags: python, list, data-conversion

I've data stored in a sequential list like this:

```
x0 y0 z(x0y0) 
x0 y1 z(x0y1)
x0 y2 z(x0y2)
     .
     .
     .
x0 y150 z(x0y150)
x1 y0 z(x1y0)
x1 y1 z(x1y1)
     .
     .
     .
x150 y148 z(x150y148)
x150 y149 z(x150y149)
x150 y150 z(x150y150)
```

Is there a simple way to convert such data in a form like this:

```
      x0      x1       x2   .   .   .   x148   x149   x150
y0    z(x0y0) z(x1y0)  z(x2y0)           .       .      .
y1    z(x0y1) z(x1y1)  z(x2y1)           .       .      .
y2    z(x0y2) z(x1y2)  z(x2y2)           .       .      .
.               .
.               .
.               . 
y148            .
y149            .
y150            .
```

in python?

I've searched for this but found no solution.

Edit: Loading data with:

```
a = numpy.loadtxt(open(file,"r"),delimiter="\t",skiprows=10)
```

gives:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.00100671,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.00201342,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   ..., 
   [ 0.14798658,  0.15      ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.14899329,  0.15      ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.15      ,  0.15      ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: There should be...but looking to see what you did try..

Comment: Is what you have a list of strings, tuples, etc.? Do you want to generate that output or just store in convenient data structure?

Comment: @schwobaseggl It is a 22500 * 3 double array and it should be converted to a 151*151 array.

Comment: @IronFist I found no similar problem. Of course one can use loops for sorting, but I thought maybe there is a function for problems like this.

Comment: You should really give a better indication of what your data looks like in python, not a diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a possible solution which may be improved:

```
import numpy
file = 'filename.txt'
a = numpy.loadtxt(open(file,"r"),delimiter="\t",skiprows=10)

xvalues = a[:,0]
yvalues = a[:,1]
zvalues = a[:,2]

diff_xvalues = []
diff_yvalues = []

for x in xvalues:
    if x not in diff_xvalues:
        diff_xvalues.append(x)

for y in yvalues:
    if y not in diff_yvalues:
        diff_yvalues.append(y)

matrix = []

for y in range(len(diff_yvalues)):
    matrix.append([])    
        for x in range(len(diff_xvalues)):
            matrix[y].append(zvalues[len(diff_xvalues)*y + x])
```